# How to use numpy arrays as input to Tensorflow CNN without mismatched dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have inputs to a tensorflow convnet as rank-4 tensors (32, 32, 3, 73257) (73257 comes from number of imgs) which are numpy arrays, but my placeholder variable for my x inputs is 2-d, (None, 3072). The 3072 comes from the img height x img width x channels. My question is, how do I reshape or use the images so that theyre compatible with the placeholder?

P.S. These images are from the SVHN cropped 32x32 dataset

```
images = np.array(features, dtype=np.float32)
...
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3072])
...
for _ in range(1000):
  batch = next_batch(50, images, labels)
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})
...
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(20000):
    batch = next_batch(50, images, labels)
    if i % 100 == 0:
      train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
          x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
      print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: images, y_: labels, keep_prob: 0.5})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have 73257 images 32 by 32 pixel holding 3 bands (e.g. rgb). You can do a

```
input = tf.transpose(input, [3, 0, 1, 2])
```

to bring the last dimension first. The tensor should then look like (73257, 32, 32, 3).

Then do

```
input = tf.reshape(input, [-1, 3072])
```

to reduce the dimension. The tensor should then look like (73257, 3072).

Comment: Got it! Thanks for your help